# Huge pagination

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, pagination

I have a lot of data and I need to offer paging over them. When I overstep the limit `from + to > 10000` elasticsearch immediately fails. I don't want to set the `index.max_result_window` to higher number because I don't always need such a limit. In fact, the limit is overstepped rarely.

I'm using ES 2.3 in AWS.

Is there some workaround? How can I achieve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use [scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/search-request-scroll.html) but I think it was never really meant for real-time paging as noted in the documentations? Perhaps you can set the max_result_window to a higher number but **only** when you need it and set it back after? It is a dynamic index setting anyway.

`curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/my_index/_settings" -d '{ "index" : { "max_result_window" : 100000 } }'`

Comment: Changing the limit according to current number of results seems as a good idea. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to you to use [scroll](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html)
It's more efficient way.

Comment: Well, but it doesn't solve my problem. Scroll will show all results, without paging, right? I need to allow user to go to 40th page without fail.

Comment: What is the size of each request?

Comment: I have a dynamic "perPage" select with "unlimited" page numbers - by unlimited I mean jump to 100th page if there is enough results. The response has approximately 60kB